# PHP htmlentities Not Working

Tags: php, html, html-entities, double-quotes, htmlspecialchars

I am retrieving text and HTML tags from a database while using this function to encode the values for the browser.

```
foreach ($row as $key => &$value){
    $value = htmlspecialchars_decode(
                 htmlentities($value,ENT_QUOTES), 
                 ENT_NOQUOTES
             );
}
```

Basically, I am looping through each row and converting quotes, single quotes, and other special characters to entities while keeping HTML tags.

However, when there's tags like `<a href="example.com">`, the quotes are duplicated twice and outputs to this:

`<a href=""example.com"">`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you currently have should [just work](https://eval.in/34914).

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes it's working now, but now it displays HTML tags as text. How do I get the HTML tags to work?

Comment: Just strip the tags with either [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) or [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Comment: @PeeHaa But I need to keep the tags so I can use them for styles.

Comment: Then just decode it on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You should use htmlentities: `htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);`